# facebook : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (OK)

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

i am using facebook sharing using javascript.
it is working fine on other browser like firefox but it is not working on chrome.

The chrome is giving error like :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (OK)

What is reason behind it? how to solve it?

please see the demo of it .... http://learning.mystore.in
please click on share and see it

Comment: I only get “user is not authorized” when clicking “share” on your demo page.